# How can you create new user group in a custom module?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to assign permissions to a new model for a specific group. This new group will be called "Product Extended User" as it enables access to "Product Extended" model and custom module.

If I do this in `ir.mode.access.csv` I expect to be enabling access to this group for the specific model.

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_product_extended_user_group,product.extended.user,model_product_extended,base.group_product_extended_user,1,1,1,1
```

However, the group is not created and hence the XMLID `base.group_product_extended_user` does not exist, and I doubt it would have to be prefixed with `base.`.

How can I create such group, not manually but importing it from custom module data file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all create `ir.model.access.csv` file and add the following code.

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_product_extended_user,product.extended.user,model_product_extended,module_name.group_product_extended_user,1,1,1,1
```

In this case model name is `product.extended` and group name is `group_product_extended_user`.

After that you will need to add this code in an xml file.

```
<record model="res.groups" id="group_product_extended_user">
    <field name="name">Group name</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module.category_id"/>
</record>
```

Add this `xml` and `ir.model.access.csv` files into data attribute of manifest file. You will be able to create a group in this way.

Comment: Thanks, how do you then refer to this specific group in the `ir.mode.access.csv` file , provided that both `xml`and `ir.mode.access.csv` are defined in the same module?

Answer (score 1):

> How do you then refer to this specific group in the `ir.model.access.csv` file, provided that both `xml` and `ir.model.access.csv` are defined in the same module?

1. In your `__openerp__.py` (or `__manifest__.py` in newer Odoo versions) file, ensure the file that creates the group is loaded before the `ir.model.access.csv` file.
2. Call it as you would any other group: `your_module_name.group_xml_id`

**ir.model.access.csv**

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_product_extended_user_group,product.extended.user,model_product_extended,your_module_name.group_xml_id,1,1,1,1
```